# Dative prepositions and seit

Tags: difference, grammatical-case, dative, accusative

I am learning via Duolingo and struggling to understand why this was the correct answer:

> Ich habe einen Hut, seit du einen Hut hast.

Why is it “… du eine**n** Hut hast” and not “du eine**m** Hut hast”?

I thought seit triggered the dative case

Comment: *Seit* is not only a preposition but also a conjunction.

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works.

Answer (score 10):

[*Seit*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/seit) is not only a preposition. It can be one, but it doesn’t have to be. If it is a preposition, it governs dative. But if it is, then its government only extends to the first noun expression following. If it were a preposition in your example, its effect would only concern *du*.

But, as I mentioned, *seit* is also a temporal conjunction. In this case, it cannot govern any cases since it is merely introducing a subordinate clause. The subordinate clause’s word order will be determined by standard grammar rules and the verb governs the relevant nouns’ cases.

Both usages can also come together in a single sentence (although that is uncommon):

> Seit<sup>{conjunction}</sup> ich von der seit<sup>{preposition}</sup> einigen Tagen geltenden Vorschrift erfahren habe, …

Answer (score 4):

"*Seit*" triggers dative case, yes. But "*einen Hut*" does not belong to "*seit*" here, it belongs to "*hast*" (-> "haben"). Und "*haben*" needs accusative case. See the first part of the sentence - "*ich habe eine**n** Hut*".